# Third and other consecutive UIButtons won't appear in the UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

Good day fellow programmers,

It has been hours now since I've tried resolving this problem. I am planning to create some kind of menu view the same to that of Facebook's iOS app. The problem is, i can only add up to two `UIButtons` in the `UIScrollView`, the third and other consecutive buttons won't show up. I hope you could help me with this.

Here is the code block:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    if(i == 0)
    {

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];    //Creates a UIButton

        button.frame = CGRectMake(25, 65, 70, 70); //sets the coordinates and dimensions of UIButton

        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //sets the background color

        [button addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //sets the target and action for the button

        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Message Board Icon-57.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image


        [subview addSubview:button];
        [button release];

        UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain]; //Creates a UIButton

        button2.frame = CGRectMake(125, 175, 70, 70); //sets the coordinates and dimensions of UIButton

        button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //sets the background color

        [button2 addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //sets the target and action for the button

        [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profile Page Icon-57.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image

        [subview addSubview:button2];
        [button2 release];


        UIButton *button3 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain]; //Creates a UIButton

        button3.frame = CGRectMake(125, 65, 70, 70); //sets the coordinates and dimensions of UIButton

        button3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //sets the background color

        [button3 addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //sets the target and action for the button

        [button3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iCalendar Icon-57.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image


        [subview addSubview:button3];
        [button3 release];


    } 
    [subview release];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

}
```

Comment: Do the buttons show up when you change the type to rounded rect?

Comment: you have to add you UIview *subview to scrollView to show it up in that and also buttons. just do, [scrollview addsubview:subview];

Comment: I've been able to spot the problem now. There were some typos in my image names and this caused the inconsistency of them being added into the UIScrollView... Thanks @dasdom and @iphonePlayer for taking the time to read my concern.

Comment: Make that an answer an check it as correct so that other people can benefit from your experience.

Comment: @dasdom sure, will do. there's a time limit yet for users with low rep like me. I'll update this after 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add you `UIView *subview` to `scrollView` to show it up in that and also buttons. just do, `[scrollView addSubview:subView];`

Comment: thanks for the heads up @iphonePlayer... The issue of my code block was more typographical than logical.